# Why this JQuery function just works with post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Why this JQuery function works with `post`? But not with `get`? I don't want to change anything in my database just to return some information...It seems that like I am passing parameters it just recognize `type: post` in `Ajax` even if my intention is not to change anything. If I don't use `type:"post"` my parameter in the controller action is going to be `null`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $(".link").click(function () {      
        var grad = $(".link").data("graduate")
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: $(".link").data("url"),       
            data: JSON.stringify( { graduate: grad }),            
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        })
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
    })
})
```

This is my controller:

```
 public ActionResult PopulateModal(CMIPGraduateVM graduate)
        {
            return PartialView(graduate);
        }
```

Comment: Because you can't pass a message body with http get.

Comment: It just needs to be `data: grad,` (and remove the `contentType` option) assuming `grad` is an object containing name/value pairs matching your model properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send data in the body of a POST request. You can only pass data with a GET request by using URL parameters, e.g. url.com?this=that&so=on

Comment: jQuery converts the data into the query string for a get. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Never new that. Surely JSON.stringify( { graduate: grad }) would break that functionality then?

Comment: That could well be it. I can't see anything else that could be the issue.

Comment: I guess when you're creating the API you're expecting a particular request type so you can route it properly. That URL might not be configured to accept GET requests.

Answer (score 0):

Add `[HttpPost]` to your controller method to allow it to accept posted data.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PopulateModal(CMIPGraduateVM graduate)
{
    return PartialView(graduate);
}
```

And `CMIPGraduateVM` needs to be a class that has the `graduate` property whose type matches the structure that you're providing with the grad variable (`var grad = $(".link").data("graduate");` not sure if this is a string or bool or object, etc).